# How to include unvalued attributes in command line ldapsearch output

Tags: csv, awk, sed, ldap-query, apacheds

I am trying to automate a piece wherein I extract 10-15 attributes using ldapsearch and format it to show in a pipe delimited CSV file.

The script works well and I am able to generate the CSV file; but there's a small issue: the number of columns returned per user are not same (as not all of the users within a particular OU will have all 15 attributes set).

this is a sample of my ldapsearch command:

/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://test-ldap.bip.dc.com -D testuser -w testpass -s sub -b "ou=users,ou=dc,o=com" "cn=*" cn sn status manager department userHireDate userTerminationDate userReHireDate userOfficeBuildingLocation userCountry | cut -d':' -f2 | sed ':a;N;$ba;s/\n\n/#/g' | tr '\n' '|' | tr '#' '\n' | awk '/./' >testop.csv

The issue is that when I run this script I get output like following:

johndoe | Doe | Active | Abraham Lincoln | Los Angeles
abelincoln | Lincoln | Active | Benjamin Franklin | Governance | 10/12/2015 05:00 | London

For someone who has other columns also populated I would get the fields like
eddiemurphy | Murphy | Active| Benjamin Franklin | Compliance | 19/01/2016 05:00 | 04/05/2016 06:00 | 09/05/2016 05:00 | New York | USA

this makes it very difficult to update in my data warehouse; so for now I am relying on good ol' Apache Directory Studio to generate the CSV format after performing LDAP search - the difference there is that Apache Directory studio also includes the blank columns (for e.g. userReHireDate / userTerminationDate as that isn't populated for all users). But with user base of 40K, it becomes very resource intensive to generate the report manually daily.

so my question is simple: is it possible to mimic the behavior of Apache Directory studio in exporting LDAP data (with the unvalued attributes also included) but on a command line?

I did research and noted that ldapsearch has -A option which includes all attributes but doesn't show their value; that isn't useful for me either as I need a flag that's applicable only for unvalued attributes.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and make sure to use the editors `{}` button to format it correctly.

Comment: Hi @mohitv109, please, can you provide an example of the ldapsearch output?

Comment: What about https://gist.github.com/dansimau/674203

I did a quick test and it seems to do the job quite well.